# Trying to install texlive but it gets stuck

Tags: texlive

This is the [output of the installation.](http://pastebin.com/mMRPWqvz)

I have no idea why this keeps happening. I've tried the installation multiple times and with every mirror it gets hung up on the same part. This is the first time I have tried installing texlive.

I use Windows 8.1 x64.

Comment: It basically says that the mirror responds that a certain file that is suppose to be in Texas live is not available on the mirror. Have you tried explicitly specifying a different mirror? There should be a list on http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html, note that you need to navigate the mirror until the url ends with "tlnet" that is the root the installer needs.

Comment: I've tried multiple mirrors and I still get the same error.

Comment: Technically, if you are using a different mirror the error is not the same, it will be a different url. Which mirror? And are you sure it is not using the new mirror, and not just falling b a ck to the KU.edu one?

Comment: [New mirror](http://i.imgur.com/7VO2CH1.png)  and this keeps happening on every mirror I've tried.

Comment: Please report this to the texlive mailing list, the list is found on tug.org. I find it very suspicious that it fails on exactly the same package each time